# Angular 404 page routing for nested modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm Using nested modules in my project

```
.
└─ AppModule
    ├─ MallModule
    ├─ OtherModule
    └─ ...
```

In the main route I only configured top-level routes:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },

  { path: '404', component: NotfoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }, // Added
]
```

Separately, I configured routes separately in each sub-modules, like:

**mall-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: MallComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent,
      },
      ...
    }
]
```

The result is, because that no other routes are defined in the main routing configs, all requests other than login/register/404 will be redirected to 404.

Is there anyway I can use a correct 404 redirection but keep the current route file structure? I don't hope to gather all route configs together.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to import the modules in the root module OR use `lazy-loading` to load other modules and use their routes

Comment: @SachinGupta yes they are working fine currently, I just want to add a 404 page. I did not use lazy-loading because the breadcrumb is not working with that.

Comment: @JasonWhite Is `{ path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }` equals to your catch-call route? how should I config it? thanks.

Comment: Please add the code for the `imports` array of the AppModule (root)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

import the 'Other' modules in your app modules, this will allow the routes defined in those modules to be used.

The updated code should look something like this:

```
imports: [
  MallModule,
  OtherModule
  RouterModule.forRoot([ // Add the configuration here, which is not a part of other module ])
]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already added them like this: `imports: [ MallModule, MallRoutingModule, OtherModule, OtherRoutingModule....]` in my `app.Module.ts`. Should I add `forRoot` part as well? Sorry I can't get your point by adding this.

Comment: When using routes in the application, you need to have at least one usage of `RouterModule.forRoot`

Comment: If you are still unable to get this done. Please consider creating a minimum reproduction on stackblitz.

Comment: thanks for your inspiration! I made an extra import of sub routing module in my code! [check this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1f6bz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) should be good!

Comment: `AppRoutingModule` should be the last in the list of imports for catch all route to work properly

Comment: @Amit not necessarily, it depends on how you configure the routes. If you have the 404 route or other common things in a separate module, you will be importing that one as the last

Comment: that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

I arrived in at this question after one module worked fine with the routing but another gave 404 for all its subpages.

The problem for me was the order in `app.modules.ts`. I had the submodules after the import of `AppRoutingModule` in the list of imports. Once I moved that last, than the routing of submodules and 404 page worked fine.

In app.module.ts.

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    SubModule,
    AuthorizationModule,
    CommonModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    ProfileModule, // this was previously defined after AppRoutinModule
    AppRoutingModule // this must be last in list for routing with 404 to work
  ]
```

and in app-routing.modules.ts.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    // https://angular.io/guide/router
    { path: 'help', component: HelpComponent },
    { path: 'terms', component: TermsComponent },
    { path: 'contact', component: ContactComponent},
    { path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

in routing load your modules like below

```
  // MallModule
  {
    path: "path",
    canLoad: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: "./modules/MallModule.module#MallModule",

  },
```